# An improper Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

While studying Lebesgue integration, I have been asked to show the following equality. $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{e^x-1}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-nx} \sin x dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$

Where the integrals are improper Riemann integrals. Here is my attempt. Integration by parts gives the second equality, so I have no problem with that. From the geometric series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-e^x}$ I do get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{e^x-1}dx =  \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx} \sin x dx$$ First equality seems to follow if I could swap the order of the sum and integral. I tried applying Levi's theorem setting $f_n=e^{-nx}\sin x$ but have trouble because I can't see if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty |f_n| \lt \infty$, which is the condition for the Levi's theorem to hold.

Comment: Just consider the set of functions $f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-nx}\sin x$. 
All these functions are majorized by the integrable function $f(x)$: $\,\,|f_N(x)|\leqslant f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}|\sin x|$. Therefore, according to the DCT,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f_N(x)dx=\int_0^\infty\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(x)dx$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Why is $f$ integrable?

Comment: $$f(x)=\frac{|\sin x|}{e^x-1}<\frac x{e^x-1}\,; \int_0^\infty\frac x{e^x-1}dx=\Gamma(2)\zeta(2)$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @Svyatoslav